# How to approach upgrading an AngularJs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, migration, upgrade

I have an older massive app that I'm assuming support for. It's an AngularJs front end that calls into a .NET MVC backend for additional processing.  In terms of trying to modernize this app, I'm not even sure where to start.  There is some organization to the code, but much of it suffers from either spaghetti coding and software entropy bloat over the years (on both the front and back ends) with business rules littered throughout the code.

Currently, we're evaluating an effort to just upgrade the front end, to the latest Angular version, which looks like it will take months to accomplish.  We've considered using a staged approach by trying to upgrade each directive or component in isolation, but to me this just feels like lipstick on a pig.  The alternative is starting from a new baseline and trying to make the two co-exist as we go through the migration.

Has anyone had a good experience upgrading an existing AngularJs that they like to share their approach?

Comment: I fell your pain.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from migrating to typescript version of angularJS. Here is a great library with TS decorators (https://github.com/vsternbach/angular-ts-decorators) like in angular+.

Plus you can try to rewrite state logic to ng-redux (https://github.com/angular-redux/ng-redux). It'll help you to migrate to ngrx in the future.

This changes could be made step by step and doesn't brake project.